# What is the rationale behind bash printf escaping/quoting functionality?

Tags: bash

Using bash 4.4, if I want to print the arguments to my script with all potentially-non-literal characters escaped then I can use:

```
printf '%q\n' "${@}"
```

and if I want the arguments quoted then I can use:

```
printf '%s\n' "${@@Q}"
```

For example:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf 'Escaped: %q\n' "${@}"
echo '---'
printf 'Quoted: %s\n' "${@@Q}"

$ ./tst.sh 'foo bar' 'other .* args'
Escaped: foo\ bar
Escaped: other\ .\*\ args
---
Quoted: 'foo bar'
Quoted: 'other .* args'
```

Why? Why don't we simply have some format specifier like `%E` for `Escaped` and `%Q` for `Quoted` instead of a format specifier of `%q` to mean `Escaped` and then a completely different, cryptic syntax of `"${*@Q}"` which when used in combination with `%s` means `Quoted`?

The use of the letter `q` rather than `E`, say, to generate Escapes is baffling but I expect there's some historical reason behind that but what I'm more interested in the technical reason behind why they couldn't use a simple `%Q` or similar printf modifier for the second case to improve my understanding of how shell works in general because right now I just don't get why the current syntax is necessary.

Comment: Notice that the `@Q` equivalent to `printf '%q\n' "${@}"` would be `printf '%s\n' "${@@Q}"`, and not `printf '%s\n' "${*@Q}"`. Not sure if that makes any difference for your question, though.

Comment: Note that `@Q` isn't new syntax that was added *just* as a quoting modifier; it's one of many new expansion-time operators added at the same time.

Comment: I'm asking for what it is about the way shell processes parameters/arguments that means there's no simple `%Q` (as I've defined it above) equivalent to `%q`.

Comment: ...because nobody bothered to add one? That's a historical question, not a technical one.

Comment: So there's no technical reason for it? OK. And what's the benefit of having `%q` escape individual chars rather than have it quote the string?

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks for the `printf '%s\n' "${@@Q}"` btw, I'll update my question.

Comment: `%q` *doesn't* reliably escape individual characters. It isn't specified to behave that way, and isn't guaranteed to do so in every instance. f/e, you'll note that it quotes strings with literal newlines with `$'...'`-style quotes. I wouldn't particularly advise generalizing from observed behavior to intent absent explicit documentation.

Comment: ...which is to say -- there is absolutely no guarantee at all that `printf %q` will continue to use backslashes in places where `${...@Q}` uses quotes in the next point release. *Both* `printf %q` and `@Q` guarantee only that their output can be reused as input (by the same shell, without offering a guarantee of compatibility with other POSIX-superset shells or even prior releases); everything beyond that is an accident of implementation.

Comment: Quoting is already just syntactic sugar for bulk escaping: `'foo' == \f\o\o`. There shouldn't be any reason to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so there's no `%Q` because no-ones bothered to implement it and the constructs that do exist (`%q` and `"${@@Q}"`) produce the output they do today just due to an implementation choice and might produce different output in future. OK, got it, thanks. If you'd like to post an answer summarizing your comments I'd accept it.

Comment: @chepner hmm, in a BRE regexp, for example, you can't just escape chars to make them literal as doing so can turn them into ERE metachars. So I wonder if it's really true to say that in all applicable cases that `'foo' == \f\o\o`. I'd have to think longer and harder about that than I'd care to right now! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @EdMorton That's a question of how the underlying RE engine processes the string it receives *after* the shell has already performed quote removal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only guarantees that can be trusted for purposes of writing scripts that use any of these facilities are those given in the documentation, as follows:

For `printf '%q'`:

> `%q` - quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input

For the `@Q` parameter transformation:

> The expansion is a string that is the value of *parameter* quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

---

Notably, there are no guarantees that *either* of them will use single-quotes, or backslashes, or any other specific form; the *only* guarantee is that both will generate output that can be reused as input.

Everything else is an undocumented implementation detail, and thus prone to change.

---

Moreover, some demonstrations that behavior of both these constructs can vary in practice from the descriptions given in the question:

```
$ nl=$'\n'
$ printf '%q\n' "$nl"  # in bash 5.0, emits $'\n', not a backslash followed by a newline
$ printf '%s\n' "${nl@Q}" # in bash 5.0, emits $'\n', not a newline in single-quotes
```

...which further acts as a demonstration that both of these constructs can generate code that isn't portable to baseline-POSIX shells, and thus the "reused as shell input" or "reused as input" specifications refer to evaluation by bash itself.

Comment: Thanks, glad I asked so I know now not to use either of them to produce visually formatted output from a script since the format they produce could change in future!

Comment: Personally, when I want something a bit more reliable, I actually call a Python interpreter; Python 2's `pipes.quote()` or Python 3's `shlex.quote()` don't have formal specifications around exact output either, but at least are guaranteed to generate output that can be parsed by POSIX shells.